# Logstash: Merge two logs into one output document

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have set syslog to send logs to logstash, with the following filters:

```
output {
  elasticsearch 
  { hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  document_id => "%{job_id}"   
}

}
filter {
    grok {
        overwrite => ["message"]
    }
    json {
     source => "message"
    }
}
```

A typical message of one of my application will have an initial state and a job_id:

```
{"job_id": "xyz782", state: "processing", job_type: "something"}
```

A few minutes or so later, another log will have the same log_id, a different state, and a processing time:

```
{"job_id": "xyz782", state:"failed", processing_time: 12.345}
```

These fields get properly loaded, but two documents are created. What I would love is for only one document to be created for the initial log, and the second log to instead update the first one, meaning the updated document would have the following fields:

```
{"job_id": "xyz782", state: "failed", job_type: "something", processing_time: 12.345}
```

As you can see in my logstash conf output, I use the job_id as the document id, however, the second message seems to replace the fields from the first message, but also erase all the fields in the first message that aren't in the second one, for instance, the job_type field present in the first message doesn't appear in the final document. This may have to do with the fact the json comes from the same field "message" both times. Is there another way to get the merging of two logs messages into one document in logstash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`aggregate`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html) filter in order to do this. The aggregate filter provides support for aggregating several log lines into one single event based on a common field value. In your case, the common field would be the `job_id` field.

Then we need another field to detect the first event vs the second event that should be aggregated. In your case, this would be the `state` field.

So you simply need to add another filter to your existing Logstash configuration, like this:

```
filter {
    ...your other filters

    if [state] == "processing" {
        aggregate {
            task_id => "%{job_id}"
        }
    } else if [state] == "failed" {
        aggregate {
            task_id => "%{job_id}"
            end_of_task => true
            timeout => 120
        }
    }
}
```

You are free to adjust the `timeout` (in seconds) depending on how long your jobs are running.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your answer, I looked at aggregate but initially thought it might be overkill since I thought I needed to do a mapping of each field I want to keep in the aggregate. So I guess I'd check on the state field being present at all rather than only failed (since we would still want to aggregate success.)  Also once the aggregation has been made, will the initial message be removed, or still be in elastic? I guess there's only one way to know! Thanks again.

Comment: The initial message doesn't make it into elastic until `end_of_task` is true, so there's nothing to remove.

Comment: Ok, so if nothing gets in elastic from the initial message, is there a way to query elastic for that job_id and know it's processing, before the second message with state failed or success is received?

Comment: Also it looks like the aggregate piece requires a "code", which according to the docs is used for mappings, as with, code => "event['sql_duration'] = map['sql_duration']" -- Is this required for each and every field we want to keep? Or only for those that would be overwritten. I'm not sure yet judging from the docs.

Comment: The `code` parameter is useful if you need to compute something (like a duration, or whatever else) that you need to store in the end event. In your case, you already have the `processing_time` field, so I guess you don't need that.