# Elasticsearch Aggregation within Index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

new Elastic Stack user here! Working in Logstash, Elasticsearch, and Kibana 5.0.0, I'm looking to form timeline information out of the following document types located in the same index:

```
{id:"...", event:"event1", type:"queued", time:"..."}
{id:"...", event:"event1", type:"start", time:"..."}
{id:"...", event:"event1", type:"stop", time:"..."}
```

where I'd like to produce something along the lines of:

```
{..., event:"event1", timeInQueue:"...", timeActive:"..."}
```

based on the delta of the timestamps.

Kibana scripted fields can perform the calculation; however, I'm unsure where to store it. Storing on the aforementioned event logs seems unnatural, and creating a new index for this aggregation seems overkill.

**What is the preferred way to accomplish this aggregation?**

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203391/logstash-merge-two-logs-into-one-output-document/35204605#35204605 (hint: use the `aggregate` logstash filter)

Comment: My Logstash input is scheduled to run every minute, so I cannot guarantee that all three event type (queued, start, stop) will be processed through the pipeline's filter at the same time. For this aggregation to work, all relevant logs would have to be available in the same filter pass, correct?

Comment: No, the `aggregate` filter will hold the data as long as you define.