# Can I store geo_shape from get geo_point in Elasticsearch 7.x?

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, geometry, kibana, geospatial

My ES 7.x system storing `geo_point` data in realtime.
like :

```
{
"id" : "john",
"age" : 26,
"geo" : "57.233, 129.11"
"address" : "Rovert Hall"
}
```

and I want to automatic store `geo_shape` data from get these stored `geo_point` data in realtime.

then, query with `id` and get `geo_shape` data for make `polygon`. How can I make it as possible ? 
If it is impossible, I want to get any advice like this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to leverage a `script` ingest processor and create a `geo_shape` (of type `Point`) on the fly.

First create the pipeline:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/point-to-shape
{
    "processors": [
      {
        "script": {
          "source": """
           def latLon = /,/.split(ctx.geo);
           ctx.shape = [
             "type" : "point",
             "coordinates" : [latLon[1], latLon[0]]
           ];
          """
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

Then we indexing your documents, simply reference that pipeline, like this:

```
PUT index/_doc/1?pipeline?point-to-shape
{
  "id" : "john",
  "age" : 26,
  "geo" : "57.233, 129.11",
  "address" : "Rovert Hall"
}
```

And then resulting document will be:

```
     {
      "geo" : "57.233, 129.11",
      "address" : "Rovert Hall",
      "shape" : {
        "coordinates" : [
          " 129.11",
          "57.233"
        ],
        "type" : "point"
      },
      "id" : "john",
      "age" : 26
    }
```

PS: you also need to make sure that your index has `shape` field that has the correct `geo_shape` mapping type.

Comment: maybe this is not my case. i want to make polygon with stacked `geo_shape` data.

Comment: Oh, you mean that you want to build a polygon from multiple points indexed in multiple documents?

Comment: yes i mean make polygon from multiple document with user_id

Comment: Can you explain how you index your documents?

Comment: now, query match with `id` and return all of stacked `geo_point`. i want to get result of query match with `id` and return `polygon` of aggs of stacked `geo_point`. can I make it as possible ?

Comment: I understand that, but my question still stands: "can you explain how you index your documents?"

Comment: now, { id : keyword, age : integer, geo : geo_point, address : text }

Comment: What client tool are you using? Logstash? Filebeat? bespoke application?

Comment: I using logstash. but i transforming data because of decrypt something before send logstash. If I need transform data, I can do that in that process.

Comment: You could make use of the Logstash [`aggregate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35204605/4604579) filter.

Comment: About how to use the aggregate filter?

Comment: thanks for your advice. but I will make it using another method without logstash.

Comment: Did the answer help at all?