# Multi line log not in the right order

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elk, logstash-file

I have a log that looks like this:

```
1613635264 host1 AAA 0.11 0.09 0.12 16 13
1613635264 host1 BBB 0.21 0.23 176141
1613635264 host2 AAA 2.08 1.76 1.38 4 3
1613635264 host2 BBB 6.21 0.12 228981
1613635264 host3 AAA 0.58 1.12 1.75 16 0
1613635264 host3 BBB 4.46 0.11 254346
1613635265 host4 AAA 1.07 1.11 1.38 16 4
1613635265 host5 AAA 18.21 17.97 19.19 5 2
1613635265 host4 BBB 3.18 0.40 105858
1613635265 host5 BBB 64.69 1.08 418177
```

AAA and BBB lines don't come in order but the timestamp (first column) is the same for the pair.

Is it possible with logstash to combine these 2 lines?

Something like this:

```
{ 
 time: 1613635264, 
 host: host1, 
 metric1: 0.11 
 metric2: 0.09 
 metric3: 0.12 
 metric4: 16 
 metric5: 13
 metric6: 0.21 
 metric7: 0.23 
 metric8: 176141
}
```

I was thinking to upsert the same document in elasticsearch.
Is that possible?

Comment: This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203391/logstash-merge-two-logs-into-one-output-document/35204605#35204605 (hint: use `aggregate` filter)

Comment: It a good idea and would solve the issue but it has the constraint of working with just 1 worker. That might have an impact on performance.

Comment: Performance is only a problem once you've witnessed it is a problem, not based on assumptions. It doesn't hurt trying

Comment: The amount of data is high and comes in bursts. It will also be distributed in the near future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I setup a unique document_id that matches the 2 pairs of rows, set doc_as_upsert=true and action=update.

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    doc_as_upsert => "true"
    action => "update"
    document_id => "%{@timestamp}%{hostname}"
  }
}
```