# Logstash aggregate fields

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am trying to configure logstash to aggregate similar syslog based on a message field and in a specific timestamp.

To make my case clear, this is an example of what I would like to do.

example: I have those junk syslog coming through my logstash

```
timestamp.         message
13:54:24.               hello
13:54:35.               hello
```

What I would like to do is have a condition that check if the message are the same and those message occurs in a specific timespan (for example 10min) I would like to aggregate them into one row, and increase the count

the output I am expecting to see is as follow

```
timestamp.         message.      count
13.54.35.               hello.              2
```

I know and I saw that there is the opportunity to aggregate the fields, but I was wondering if there is a chance to do this aggregation based on a specific time range

If anyone can help me I would be extremely grateful as I am new to logstash and I have the problem that in my server I am receiving tons of junk syslog and I would like to reduce that amount.

So far I did some cleaning with this configuration

```
input {
  syslog {
    port => 514
 }
}
filter {
  prune {
    whitelist_names =>["timestamp","message","newfield"]
  }
  mutate {
        add_field => {"newfield" => "%{@timestamp}%{message}"}
      }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
     hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
         index => "logstash_index"
 }
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
 }
}
```

Now I just need to do the aggregation.

Thank you so much for your help guys

EDIT:
Following the documentation, I put in place this configuration:

```
input {
  syslog {
    port => 514
 }
}
filter {
  prune {
    whitelist_names =>["timestamp","message","newfield"]
  }
  mutate {
        add_field => {"newfield" => "%{@timestamp}%{message}"}
  }
  if [message] =~ "MESSAGE FROM" {
      aggregate {
        task_id => "%{message}"
        code => "map['message'] ||= 0; map['message'] += 1;"
        push_map_as_event_on_timeout => true
        timeout_task_id_field => "message"
        timeout => 60
        inactivity_timeout => 50
        timeout_tags => ['_aggregatetimeout']
        timeout_code => "event.set('count_message', event.get('message') > 1)"
         }
    }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
     hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
         index => "logstash_index"
 }
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
 }
}
```

I don't get any error but the output is not what I am expecting.
The actual output is that it create a tag field (Good) passing an array with `_aggregationtimeout` and `_aggregationexception`

```
{
       "message" => "<88>MESSAGE FROM\r\n",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_aggregatetimeout",
        [1] "_aggregateexception"
    ],
    "@timestamp" => 2021-07-23T12:10:45.646Z,
      "@version" => "1"
}
```

Comment: The `aggregate` filter plugin allows you to aggregate based on a [timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203391/logstash-merge-two-logs-into-one-output-document/35204605#35204605), very similar to the [example given in the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html#plugins-filters-aggregate-example5)

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work exactly as expected. I will edit mi post with the output and the config file

Comment: @NaydenVan you might try `event.set('count_message', event.get('message'))` - I ran into this too and thought the documentation was confusing